# How to remove validation when a form is closed flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I have a form with a textformfield.
 In the textFormField, I have a validator:

```
validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'description' : null,
```

```
TextFormField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Description',
              border: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              controller: controllerTitle,
              maxLines: null,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'description' : null,
              onSaved: (val) => title = val,
),
```

I have a popup form with a button 'close' and 'push'. When the form is empty and I press the push button validation triggers. Once I pressed the close button just after the push button a form closes and when I open a form one more time I can see this validation text in red, How can I clear my validation when the form is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

> setState(() {});

method to close button.